# Can I have a Wordpress site at https://mysite.pro and a AWS S3 app in https://app.mysite.pro?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, https, dns

If I buy the domain mysite.pro, can I have a wordpress site there, in some hosting (different from Amazon), and have the subdomain for a S3 Amazon AWS application, at Amazon servers? All in https.

That is, https://mysite.pro for my wordpress site, and https://app.mysite.pro for an application in S3 AWS environment.

Is that technically possible?

Thanks.

UPDATE:
I already have a wordpresss site at https://arquitecteo.es. I created the subdomain blog.arquitecteo.es with a simple html page but I want that url to be the url for my S3 app hosted in AWS.

I saw this amazing tutorial where everything is explained for a domain, but not subdomain. Maybe you would like to take a look and see what I mean:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lB4DTqMEumY&t=880s&ab_channel=EsterlingAccime

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's nothing preventing this. Although S3 doesn't support SSL certificates on custom domain names natively, so people usually place CloudFront in front of the S3 bucket to serve the SSL certificate.

Comment: Domain or subdomain would not make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

By using DNS you can have a specific subdomain "app.mysite.pro" resolve to a different target endpoint.

For HTTPS you will need to obtain an SSL certificate for your domain (and any subdomains that you will use).

If you are intending to host "mysite.pro" on a single host you will need to either purchase an SSL for this domain or use a service like [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) to obtain the SSL to serve.

However, if you will be using multiple distributed hosts you would use a load balancer to distribute traffic across your hosts using an [ELB](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/). You would integrate this with an SSL from [ACM](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/) at no cost.

It will be tricky for your S3 scenario though as you cannot use just S3 to serve HTTPS traffic for your application. This is because all S3 domains will serve the S3 SSL rather than your own.

You can get around this by creating a [CloudFront distribution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Introduction.html) that resides in front of your S3 bucket. CloudFront supports certificates via ACM.

More information is available in the [How do I use CloudFront to serve HTTPS requests for my Amazon S3 bucket?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-https-requests-s3/) article.